# python/django for loop and list attributes

Tags: python, django, list, for-loop

So, i'm studying the Django Book, and django documentation, and I can't understand this example:

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is about templates and i don't how to code the Context. How can i get attribute called "name" from a list ? If i create a dictionary it will be impossible to use for loop like in this example. I have coded it like this but it's not working:

```
athlete_list = {'name' = ['Athlete1', 'Athlete2', 'Athlete3']}
Context({'athlete_list':athlete_list})
```

if i change athlete_list variable to a normal list (not a dictionary) the "athlete.name" in the template won't work too. I don't think it's a mistake in a book, and it's probably very easy to solve, but i can't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suspect that `athlete_list` is a QuerySet object containing `Athlete` models... (does that get mentioned anywhere?). The models will then have a `.name` or `.age` or `.sport` or whatever...

**update** - just looked at http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html - which actually doesn't appear to be the best example....

To keep the template as is, you can return a context of a list of dicts, eg:

```
[ {'name': 'bob'}, {'name': 'jim'}, {'name': 'joe'} ]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, it's working now of course. They didn't mentioned anywhere how to code the context, and now i can see that it's really not the best example :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the template,you should return below.

```
athlete_list = ({'name':'Athlete1'},{'name':'Athlete2'},{'name':'Athlete3'})

Context({'athlete_list':athlete_list})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your athlete_list is actually a dict

```
<ul>
{% for athlete_name in athlete_list.name %}
    <li>{{ athlete_name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

in templates you can access dictionary keys through `.` instead of through `[]`

so in your template `{{ athleate_list.name }}`

would be a list of strings `# ['Athlete1', 'Athlete2', 'Athlete3']`

Comment: This is working too of course , but i wanted to use the template just as it is in the book. Thanks anyway